# Couldn't find hostdump.sh utility

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to backup and recovery in Unix. I came across the hostdump.sh utility which is an automated script as I have read. But when I searched on Google to find the script, I didn't see any result on that. Could anyone give me some idea, if the script has to be written by the user himself.

Comment: Except that the URLs are not allowed, I'd suggest [LMGTFY](http://tinyurl.com/kra4efk).  I got a page full of references when I search on Google for 'hostdump.sh'.  Did you not get a similar page full?

Comment: Sorry @JonathanLeffler I think you didn't get my question. I just want to know the internal script behind this utility.. and how it works.. Since I didn't get it just by googling.. therefore I have posted this as a question.